# Custom Module - Page not found

Tags: routes, drupal-8

Complete Drupal newbie, I've gone through several tutorials and other threads to try and figure out why I'm getting a Page not found response for the following.

directory structure:

```
web
--- modules
---- custom
------ school
-------- school.info.yml
-------- school.routing.yml
-------- src
---------- Controller
------------ SchoolController.php
```

school.info.yml:

```
name: 'School Module'
type: module
description: 'Handles all school details'
package: Sample
core: 8.x
```

school.routing.yml:

```
school.edit:
  path: '/admin/school/edit'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\school\Controller\SchoolController::edit'
    _title: 'Edit School'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

SchoolController:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\school\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * School Controller
 */
class SchoolController extends ControllerBase {

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit() {
        return new Response('testing');
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: it appears there may have been an issue with my Drupal installation, after completing a fresh install and duplicating the module this seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works.
You have to clear the [Drupal cache](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/prevent-cache-clear.html) or you forget to enable your module.

Comment: I'm afraid I've already tried clearing the cache multiple times, as well as uninstalling and re-installing the module, and I still seem to be getting the same response.

Comment: Based on your question edit code works as designed so it was something else that was not described here. :)